# Why Jquery don't work in widgets of wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

Here is my page: https://3brow.com/loja
Here is all the code that I already tried.
All tried to use *$(document).ready(function()* but also, didn't work.

```
$('#select2-select-pa_cor-container:contains("Todoscores")').text('another text');

$('#select2-select-pa_cor-container').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('TodosCores', 'another text')); 
});

$("#select2-select-pa_cor-container p:contains('TodosCores')").html("another text");

$('#select2-select-pa_cor-container:contains("TodosCores")').text('another text');
$('#select2-select-pa_cor-container').html($(this).html().replace('TodosCores','another text'));

$('#select2-select-pa_cor-container').each(function() {

   var text = $(this).html();
   $(this).html(text.replace('TodosCores', 'another text')); 

});

$( "#select2-select-pa_cor-container" ).replaceWith( "<span>another text</span>" );
```

I have to use a "display:none" and "before" to "work".

I try to change a placeholder of another div and with the same code I try with another div and work. I'm using wordpress and both that didn't work are widgets.
Can anyone explain why in widget this code don't work and how could I "fix" that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you try replace this line:

```
$('#select2-select-pa_cor-container').html($(this).html().replace('TodosCores','another text'));
```

for this:

```
$('#select2-select-pa_cor-container').html($('#select2-select-pa_cor-container').html().replace('TodosCores','another text'));
```

?

I think your not using well the `this` object.

Comment: Yes. I just forgot to put there. What's is funny is that I have another widget that work Jquery.